# Does inserting memory sync barrier after writing and before reading sharing variable also ensure the cache coherency

Tags: c, multithreading, caching, assembly, pthreads

If a variable(not volatile) is read/write accessed by two threads without using locking and to avoid locking and volatile I am using memory sync barriers before reading and after writing the variable.

I read memory sync barrier just serializes the read/write operations but does that mean the write/read will be reflected in parallel other threads. Does that cause processor cache to be invalidated so that the thread can latest value instead of value in cache ?

The reason I am not using locks/volatile variable is I am just trying to learn the use memory sync barrier. may be this can help me to remove the overhead of locks.

Comment: Your question is grammatically challenged. Also, `cache coherency != memory ordering`. They're separate problems.

Comment: Thanks, then the memory ordering can be handled by sync barriers but do you know how cache coherency can be handled in this case ?

Comment: Fox example, if you lock/unlock mutex, it internally issues the memory sync barrier so i thought issuing memory sync barrier also invalidates the cache because i always get correct value without using volatile keyword when i use mutex. (I also compile my program with -O3 to enable all optimizations )

Comment: Why don't you read up on cache coherency protocols? Processors use something like MESI to keep the cache coherent. Memory ordering is a *different* problem, and one that exists even in the absence of caches.

Comment: ok thanks will read that.

Comment: if you lock/unlock mutex, it internally issues the memory sync barrier so i thought issuing memory sync barrier also invalidates the cache because i always get correct value without using volatile keyword when i use mutex. (I also compile my program with -O3 to enable all optimizations ).

Comment: what i am trying to is to remove the locks and volatiles from my code using memory sync barriers. do you have any suggestion how can i achieve this with cache coherency ?

Comment: Why do you keep on with cache coherency? It's a red herring and has nothing to do with your problem. As I've said, memory ordering is necessary in multiprocessor systems even **in the absence of caches**.

Comment: Normally, cache coherency is always maintained: any write operation by one core or processor will invalidate the the affected cache lines in all other cores or processors. This doesn't solve the issue of out of order operations between cores or processors which is what the memory sync barriers are used for.

Comment: Thanks a lot rcgldr for clarification. This answers my question